# Adding a new learner to the mlr3 environment (grpreg)

Tags: mlr3

How might I use the [grpreg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grpreg/grpreg.pdf) package with mlr3 (esp with the resamplings etc)? I did a search and came across the create_learner function but found the arguments confusing (I don't know what are the correct create_learner argument values when using the grpreg functions). grpreg has a lot in common with glmnet, where the latter has been incorporated into the mlr3 environment... Is there an easy way/step-by-step guide on what was done for glmnet, which I can follow to use grpreg's learners (e.g. how were the argument values determined wrt the glmnet functions)? Is it straightforward for mlr3/mlr developers to add this new learner? That would be most very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a full book section available which explains [how new learners can be created](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/extending.html#extending-learners).

(PS: I find the title of your question a bit confusing as the content is not really related to it)